# Clojure: Calling .invoke without knowing arg types at compile time

Tags: javafx, clojure, javafx-8

I'm trying to figure out a way to `.invoke()` methods of a single arg, without knowing the type of the arg at runtime.

For example, by passing a property name to the following function, I'd like to set the property's value.  For now it's hard-coded as `Double/TYPE`, but really the function should be allowed to take any type of `value` arg.

The property names, and therefore the type of arg `value` is not known until runtime, however it appears the method requires an array of primitives, at least for number types.

```
(defn set-prop-val!
  "Sets property value to value.  Uses reflection."
  [obj prop value]
  (let [methodname (str "set" prop)]
    (.. obj
        getClass
        (getMethod methodname (into-array [Double/TYPE]))
        (invoke obj (into-array [value]) ))))

(set-prop-val! (Button.) "TranslateX" 13.99)
```

In the above function, trying instead `(getMethod methodname (into-array [(class value)]))` doesn't work, and I get `NoSuchMethodException javafx.scene.control.Button.setTranslateX(java.lang.Double)` because it wants a `double` not a `Double`.

What I'd like to do is for numbers to get the primitive type at runtime, but all attempts at calling a static method from an instance have failed, eg `(. (class 19.5) TYPE)` (in this case I get `IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: TYPE for class java.lang.Class`)

It seems only `Double/TYPE` works, even though `(= (class 19.5) Double)` returns `true`.

So a few questions come out of this:

1. How do I call a static method, such as `TYPE` from an instance?
2. Is there a use for `double-array` here?  That will get me the array to carry the values for the `.invoke`, which doesn't even appear necessary anyway, but not the `Class[double]` array needed for `.getMethod`.
3. Should I use `clojure.reflect` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I found I could just use `clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod` to do exactly what I need.